# How to pass the userID value after clicking Submit button php

Tags: php

I'm facing some error when i click submit button, the value for userID is not passed. below is my code.

```
<div> <input type='hidden' id='userID' value="<?$inputs ['userID'] ?? '' ?>" >
        </div>
        <button type='submit' name="update">Update</button>
```

after clicking Update button, the info will be passed to function. But the value passed for the userID is NULL. Can someone assist me?

Comment: Is it wrapped in a form? Calling a JS function?

Comment: You hidden field has no value, because you did not actually create any _output_ in the PHP block inside the attribute value.

Answer (score 0):

If you have wrapped your form by form tag you should have name attribute to send your data

```php
<form action="destination.php">
<div> <input type='hidden' name='userId' id='userID' value="<?$inputs ['userID'] ?? '' ?>" >

<button type='submit' name="update">Update</button>


</form>
```